# How to pass a javascript/jquery function from one html page to another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hyperlink

I have this page [articles](http://agencystudy.com/eic/microsites/microsites-02/articles.html)

In this page i have nav links on the left, and content loading on the right.

```
function showonlyone(thechosenone) {
 $('div[name|="newboxes"]').each(function(index) {
      if ($(this).attr("id") == thechosenone) {
           $(this).show(200);
      }
      else {
           $(this).hide(600);
      }
 });
}
```

my nav looks like this

```
<ul>
        <li><a id="myHeader1" href="javascript:showonlyone('articles');" >ARTICLES</a></li>
        <li><a id="myHeader1" href="javascript:showonlyone('whitepapers');" >WHITE PAPERS</a></li>
        <li><a id="myHeader1" href="javascript:showonlyone('brochures');" >BROCHURES</a></li>
    </ul>
```

and my content is in div like the following

```
<div id="articles" name="newboxes" style="display:none;">
<div id="whitepapers" name="newboxes" style="display:none;">
<div id="brochures" name="newboxes" style="display:none;">
```

Basically this page, is an interior page. 
I have a home page, that i would like to have links to each section on, so the section i want shows up already so user doesn't have to click again.

Any idea how i do this?

Thank you for any help, and I apologize if i'm not using correct terminology.

Comment: you should avoid duplicate ID's like "myHeader1". Anyway just call `showonlyone('articles')` on dom ready event

Comment: I see thank you for your help! i'll remove the id="myHeader1" i don't really need that stuff anyway.

But could you be more specific on calling that on dom ready event? sorry i'm very new to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

going by what i understand from your question is that..
u have links on home page.. 
when user clicks these links you want that particular section to be already opened when the interior page opens
like when user click "articles" then in the interior page the **articles div** should be visible
for this you will have to use **hash tags** in the following manner

on your home page..
provide the links with a hash tag like this

```
http://agencystudy.com/eic/microsites/microsites-02/articles.html#articles
```

then in your interior page in document ready event

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(window.location.hash).show(200);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

if I well understood your question, on page "articles" just call `showonlyone` function

```
$(function() { // DOMready
   showonlyone('articles');
});
```

and repeat this code for every internal page, changing the parameter